# Swappiness getting reset to default on reboot

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, swap

I wanted to set `vm.swappiness` value for my Amazon EC2 instance runnign RedHat Enterprise 7. I am able to set it manually after machine starts using

`sudo sysctl -w vm.swappiness=10`

But `vm.swappiness` gets reset to default 30 once I stop and start my instance. I googled for it and found couple of solutions like

- Adding `vm.swappiness = 10` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. But this didn't work.
- Adding `vm.swappiness = 10` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and adding `sysctl -p` in `/etc/rc.local`. This also didn't work. When I run `sysctl -p` manually, it works correctly.

Comment: Please mention in title that it's RedHat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Found solution after consulting AWS support for same. Need to change the value in `/usr/lib/tuned/virtual-guest/tuned.conf`.